# Guess Number Game in Java

Tags: java

How would I make my game have multiple lives until I can finally get the correct number?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessNumberOneTime {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Generate a random number to be guessed
    int number = (int)(Math.random() * 101);

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Guess a magic number between 0 and 100");

    // Prompt the user to guess the number
    System.out.print("\nEnter your guess: ");
    int guess = input.nextInt();

    if (guess == number)
      System.out.println("Yes, the number is " + number);
    else if (guess > number)
      System.out.println("Your guess is too high");
    else 
      System.out.println("Your guess is too low");    
  }
```

Comment: Use a [while loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) or [for loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html). Don't exit the loop until they run out of lives.

Comment: Welcome to slashdot. Please show us what you've tried so far to resolve the problem and what are the pitfall you're encontering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for your program to have multiple lives initialize a variable called guess and then run the `int number` through a while loop until the correct number has been chosen! Here’s an example of what you could do:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class GuessNumber {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Generate a random number to be guessed
    int number = (int)(Math.random() * 101);

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Guess a magic number between 0 and 100");

    int guess = -1;
    while (guess != number) {
      // Prompt the user to guess the number
      System.out.print("\nEnter your guess: ");
      guess = input.nextInt();

      if (guess == number)
        System.out.println("Yes, the number is " + number);
      else if (guess > number)
        System.out.println("Your guess is too high");
      else
        System.out.println("Your guess is too low");
    } // End of loop
  }
}
```

Comment: that makes sense to use the =! operator until the user inputs the answer! thank you!