# number guessing game not working

Tags: java

Apparently my code is not working according to an automated test and doesn't give me a pass for my solution, however when I run it it seems to work fine. I'm wondering what's wrong with my code?:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessingNumberGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numberDrawn = drawNumber();

        int i = 1;
        boolean correct = false;

        while (correct == false) {

        System.out.print("Guess a number: ");
        int guess = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

        if (guess == numberDrawn) {
            System.out.println("Congratulations, your guess is correct!");
            correct = true;

        } else if (guess < numberDrawn) {
                    System.out.println("The number is lesser, guesses made: " + i);
                                i++;
                    } else if (guess > numberDrawn) {
                        System.out.println("The number is greater, guess made: " + i);
                                    i++;
        }
        }
    }

    // DO NOT MODIFY THIS!
    private static int drawNumber() {
        return new Random().nextInt(101);
    }
}
```

It is exercise 41 on the University of Helsinki online Java course, the exercise details are here: http://mooc.cs.helsinki.fi/programming-part1/material-2013/week-2?noredirect=1#e41

The errors that I get are:

- If guess is too small, program should print "The number is greater".
- If guess is too large, program should print "The number is lesser".
- If the drawn number is 1 and user input is 0, 1, program should at first print
  "The number is greater", and after that "Congratulations, your guess is correct!"
- If the drawn number is 1 and user input is 2, 1, program should at first print
  "The number is lesser", and after that "Congratulations, your guess is correct!"

Thank you

Comment: It looks like you have your `<` and `>` flipped. (If `guess < numberDrawn`, it means the guess was too small, so you should print "The number is greater.")

Comment: As a hint for style you could simply write `while(!correct){...}` . The `!` will negate the boolean value of `correct`

Comment: You additionally print the number of guesses which have been made so far, but according to your errors bullet points these should not be there or did I misunderstood this?

Comment: The "DO NOT MODIFY THIS!" comment make me laugh

Comment: Thanks Alex Lew, what a silly mistake I made.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Guess Number Game in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33875924/guess-number-game-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

You have simple logic mistake

When the number is lesser condition should be `guess > numberDrawn` or the number is greater it should be `guess < numberDrawn`:

```
    if (guess == numberDrawn) {
         System.out.println("Congratulations, your guess is correct!");
         correct = true;
    } else if (guess > numberDrawn) {
                System.out.println("The number is lesser, guesses made: " + i);           
                i++;
    } else if (guess < numberDrawn) {
                System.out.println("The number is greater, guess made: " + i);           
                i++;
    }
```